# Elden Ring suddenly started stuttering

Tags: technical-issues, elden-ring

So, I had finished Elden Ring back in April 2022 (last year). I wanted to play NG+ , after the DLC was announced. So, I started again, after 1+ year.

However, the game was completely unplayable due to stuttering. In between my last and current plays. I must have formatted my PC and updated all graphics and Windows. I tried to reduce the resolution, but nothing works. I also tried to

- Turn on VSync on NVidia Control Panel
- Set Triple Buffering to Yes on NVidia Control Panel

They too aren't working. Any help ?